# Lebesgue integrable implies zero almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that for every continuous $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$, $\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R} fg \ dm=0$. Show that $f$ is zero a.e.

This is a qualifier sample problem and my idea is to proceed by contradiction. My problem here is that $f$ is not necessarily nonnegative so I'm having difficulties on establishing inequalities to arrive at a contradiction. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: You can always write a measurable function $f$ as $f =f^++f^-$ where $f^+(x)=\max\{0,f(x)\}$ and $f^-(x)=-\max\{0,-f(x)\}$. So $f\neq 0$ a.e. implies $f^+$ or $f^-$ must be non-zero on some set of positive measure.

Comment: If we write $f$ in that form, I don't see why that works.

Comment: $\int_\mathbb R fg~dm=0$ for every continuous $g$ implies that $\int_I f~dm=0$ over every interval $I$. Let $g$ be a bump with height 1 on $I$ and very steep slopes. If $f$ were to have some oscillatory/cancellation behavior, then it will need to oscillate infinitely fast to do so on every interval. Furthermore there must be a simple function that approximates $f$ on $I$. Such a simple function must be very small on any set of positive measure. Not rigorous, just some thoughts.

Comment: Hint: You can use the dominated convergence theorem to show that this implies that $\int_a^b f(t) dt = 0$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. What does the Lebesgue differentiation theorem tell you?

Comment: Do you know Littlewood's three principles?  He claimed almost any problem in Lebesgue measure theory can be solved using one of them.

Comment: You can **cheat**; the assumptions imply that the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ikx}\,dx$ vanishes, and since the Fourier transform is injective, $f=0$. The cheating part is that you should prove that the Fourier transform is injective, of course.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro LOL. Now we are cheating, we could also say that $f$ is weakly differentiable with weak derivative $0$, so it must be constant a.e.. But then the only integrable constant is zero. Here we did all kind of cheating (and circle reasoning)...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $b\in L^\infty(\mathbb R),$ then there exists a sequence $g_n$ of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ such that $\|g_n\|_\infty\le \|b\|_\infty$ for all $n,$ and $g_n \to b$ pointwise a.e.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\sign}{\operatorname{sign}}$By taking continuous functions $g$ with support in $(0,1)$, we can conclude that the statement is true for all functions $g\in C_c((0,1))$, i.e. functions with compact support in $(0,1)$, right? So let us focus on the function $f|_{(0,1)}$ on $(0,1)$ and forget about $\mathbb R$ for the moment.

Since $(0,1)$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure $m$ is a finite measure space, [Lusin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem) tells us that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a compact set $K_\varepsilon\subset (0,1)$ such that  $m((0,1)\setminus K_\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$ and a continuous function $h_\varepsilon$ with compact support such that $h_\varepsilon=\sign(f)$ on $K_\varepsilon$ and $\sup_{x\in (0,1)}|h_\varepsilon(x) |\leq 1$. This means for instance that we can take $g=h_\varepsilon$ and get
$$0=\int_{(0,1)}fg\,dm=\int_{K_\varepsilon} |f|\,dm + \int_{(0,1)\setminus K_\varepsilon}fh_{\varepsilon}\,dm$$
Now we take a sequence of $\varepsilon$s, say $\varepsilon_n=1/n$, and apply DCT (HOW?) to get that 
$$\int_{(0,1)}|f|\,dm=0$$
which implies $f=0$ a.e. on $(0,1)$. But we could also take $(a,b)$ instead of $(0,1)$, right? Of course, try it yourself and see if you understand it.

Comment: Edited. I have added a crucial thing about $h_\varepsilon$.